# Set theory - Axiom of specification

Tags: set-theory

I am reading Naive Set Theorey by Halmos, and am struggling to understand the Axiom of specification.

I understand:
Axiom of specification. To every set A and to every condition S( x) there corresponds a set B whose elements are exactly those elements x of A for which S( x) holds.

But I don’t understand what Halmos is talking about here:
It follows that, whatever the set A may be, if B = {x ∈ A: x ∉′ x}, then, for all y,
Can it be that B ∈ A? We proceed to prove that the answer is no. Indeed, if B ∈ A, then either B ∈ B also (unlikely, but not obviously impossible), or else B ∈′ B. If B ∈ B, then, by (*), the assumption B ∈ A yields B ∈′ B–a contradiction. If B ∈′ B, then, by (*) again, the assumption B ∈ A yields B ∈ B–a contradiction again. This completes the proof that B ∈ A is impossible, so that we must have B ∈′ A. The most interesting part of this conclusion is that there exists something (namely B) that does not belong to A. The set A in this argument was quite arbitrary. We have proved, in other words, that nothing contains everything,

How can B ever belong to B?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why cannot B belong to B?

Comment: If B is a set, it was in the previous chapter of the book that this is never true

Comment: What is ∉′${ }$?

Comment: That is does not belong to

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could You cite the relevant part of the previous chapter?

Comment: From previous chapter: That is: A ⊂ A is always true; is A ∈ A ever true? It is certainly not true of any reasonable set that anyone has ever seen.

Comment: ok, this is why the (excellent) book is called "naive" set theory, it cannot be shown that such a set doesn´t exist, that´s why one has to consider such a case in a proof, but You have probably never "seen" such a set

Comment: Right, thank you!

Comment: You´re welcome!